# PowerShell edit #text from XML attributes

Tags: xml, powershell

The problem is the following:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $USSExternalContentTypeFile)   
$xml.Model.Properties.Property. ....
$xml.Save($USSExternalContentTypeFile)
```

Name                                                                                   Type                                                                                   #text
----                                                                                   ----                                                                                   -----
Connect Integrated Security                                                            System.String                                                                          textxtxtxtxtxtxtxt

```
<Property Name="Connect Integrated Security" Type="System.String">SSPI</Property>
```

Help multiple xml attribute to replace #text?

Finish:
    Property[2].'#text' = 'foo'

Comment: `$x = [xml]'<name>hello</name>'`

Comment: `$x.SelectSingleNode('name').'#text' = 'world'`

Answer (score 4):

Try this way to access the #text property:

```
PS> $xml = [xml]'<Property Name="Connect Integrated Security" Type="System.String">SSPI</Property> '
PS> $xml.Property

Name                                    Type                                    #text
----                                    ----                                    -----
Connect Integrated Security             System.String                           SSPI

PS> $xml.Property.'#text' = 'foo'

PS> $xml.Property

Name                                    Type                                    #text
----                                    ----                                    -----
Connect Integrated Security             System.String                           foo
```

Comment: This not work!  $xml = [xml](Get-Content $USSExternalContentTypeFile)   
$xml.Model.Properties.Property. ....
$xml.Save($USSExternalContentTypeFile)

Comment: $xml.Model.Properties.Property | where { $_.Name -eq "Connect Integrated Security" }

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to PowerShell's automatic NoteProperties for XML nodes you could also use XPath to get the nodes you want. Say if you want all Property nodes with a name attribute of "Connect Integrated Security" you could use:

```
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//Property[@Name='Connect Integrated Security']")
$nodes | % {
    $_."#text" = "SomeNewValue" # Changes SSPI to this.
}
```

If you want to stick with the NoteProperties this will probably work:

```
$xml.Model.Properties.Property | % {
    $_."#text" = "SomeNewValue" # Changes SSPI to this.
}
```

Comment: Finish:
    Property[2].'#text' = 'foo'

Comment: Upvoted because answer shows how to access the text property of a node ("#text")