# Why is the '#text' property not documented on the official Microsoft class definition page (XmlAttribute)?

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

[Official MS Documentation for XmlAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlattribute?view=net-7.0)

`Value` is documented. But not #text, despite it working just fine.

See these posts using it:

[access #text property of XMLAttribute in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259590/access-text-property-of-xmlattribute-in-powershell)

[PowerShell edit #text from XML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325652/powershell-edit-text-from-xml-attributes)

And this guide:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml/

This code works:

```
[SelectXmlInfo]$out = Select-Xml '//*[local-name()="svg"]/@viewBox' -Path $TheSVGFile
$out | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Node.GetType()
    $_.Node.'#text'
}
```

Output:

[image]

Where is the documentation located for this mysterious property/attribute?

Comment: `#text` as property name is a powershell thing stringifying xml nodes as property names thats why is not documented. see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.name?view=net-7.0#property-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#text` as Property Name is a PowerShell thing using the `.ToString()` representation of an Xml Node as property name that's why you don't see documented **as a property** in the [`XmlNode` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode?view=net-7.0) or any of its descendants.

Relevant documentation in this case is [`XmlNode.Name` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.name?view=net-7.0#property-value) and [`XmlNodeType` Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodetype?view=net-7.0).

```bash
$xml = [xml]::new()
$node = $xml.CreateTextNode('foo')
[pscustomobject]@{
    $node.ToString() = $node.Value
}

# #text
# -----
# foo
```